# WM_POWERBROADCAST not received by message-only window in Windows XP

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-xp, broadcast, windows-messages

I'm trying to find out whether broadcast messages will be sent to message only windows, i.e. created as:

```
hWnd = CreateWindow(MAKEINTATOM(RegisterClass(&wnd)), NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HWND_MESSAGE, hInstance, 0);
```

Thing is that I don't get any broadcast messages to that window... ;)

Comment: Are you saying that you don't get *any* broadcast messages, or just that you don't get `WM_POWERBROADCAST`?

Comment: I don't get the WM_QUERYENDSESSION message either. Thing is that I've read somewhere that HWND_MESSAGE windows don't receive OS broadcasts, and that you'd need a toplevel window for that. But I haven't found any documentation to support/debunk this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your suspicions are correct. Message-only windows (those created by specifying `HWND_MESSAGE` for the `hwndParent` parameter of the `CreateWindowEx` function) do not receive broadcast notifications:

> **A message-only window** enables you to send and receive messages. It is not visible, has no z-order, cannot be enumerated, and **does not receive broadcast messages**. The window simply dispatches messages.

Reference: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632599%28VS.85%29.aspx#message_only)

Comment: RegisterPowerSettingNotification is Vista and later, this problem is on XP ;)

Comment: @Robert: Yup, no problem. Sorry it wasn't answer you were hoping for. ;-) But it's always good to get confirmation from the docs. Just create a top-level window, but without the `WS_VISIBLE` style.